# Are there any good examples of ajax paging?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, paging

i have a page that displays large datasets into html tables.  how can i add paging without having to refresh the whole page each time i change pages

Comment: i have seen tons of example of doing paging in asp.net mvc where i add /page to the url. which works fine but i want to learn about solutions that dont refresh the whole page

Comment: And have you done any research yourself? It is simply a matter of loading the new page in format that you can capture with an ajax call (say, xml, or pure html) and then writing it to the new location.

Comment: i am new to ajax and jquery / javascript so i am trying to figure the best place to see a simple example to work off of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just need a page for your form submission, and given the search criteria and a page number, it just returns the next page, preferably as a json result, so you can just change the cells in the current table, which will be faster to render.

It appears this is an example of what you want:
http://encosia.com/2008/08/20/easily-build-powerful-client-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/